# Python, combine function

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.dragTo(794,370,duration = 0.40)
pyautogui.dragTo(1050,525,duration = 0.40)
```

I have delay  between here 2 code. How can I combine them so that there is no delay?

Comment: How could you drag your mouse pointer to 2 different locations simultaneously?

Comment: when the mouse moves to the coordinate it goes holding the right mouse button. and when the second code begins, he releases the mouse and again holding it goes to another coordinate

I want it to not release after the first dragTo

Comment: That's not simultaneous, so you need to have two different `dragTo` calls

Comment: I want it to not release mouse left button after the first dragTo